# Redirect to 400 on xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am posting using xmlhttprequest as follows

```
// xhr response handler
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4) {


        handleSuccess(xhr.responseText);

    } else if (xhr.status == 400) {
        console.log("400000000000000000000");
        // alert("Unable to process data");
        // window.location.reload();
        sendRequestSimple("400.html");
        // fetch("/400")
        //     .then(function() {
        //         console.log("ok");
        //     }).catch(function() {
        //     console.log("error");
        // });
    }
    else {
        console.trace("status: " + xhr.status);
        console.trace("readystate: " + xhr.readyState);
    }
};

// Send the Data.
xhr.send(formData);
```

I am unable to get it to redirect to 400 error page in an error scenario. What is the correct way? As coded above..it will not redirect.

Comment: What does your `sendRequestSimple` function look like? If you just need a simple "redirect", using `window.location.replace(url)` should be enough.

Comment: You want to redirect the request or the user?

Comment: thanks @helb thats what i needed. my sendRequestSimple was generating a new xmkhttprequest instead of using window.loc.....

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the error using

```
console.log(xhr.status);
```

before starting if condition.

status indicates if server response is ok.
In general words, when you got an status

500 - 599: the server had an error

400 - 499: this is a client error (Ex: 404 page not found)

300 - 399: then exists a redirect

200 - 299: then it is correct and

100 - 199: means information message

and inside your elseif section replace

```
sendRequestSimple("400.html");
```

with

```
window.location = "Your html path";
```

or

```
window.location.href = "demo2.html";
```